# How to convert a bytearray in a tuple in a list to a string?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from my mysql database using python:

```
import mysql.connector

myDB = mysql.connector.connect(
host = "<host>",
port = "<port>",
user = "<user>",
password = "<passwd>",
database = "<database>"
)

mycursor = myDB.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT binaryValue FROM users")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
```

This reads a column in my database called binaryValue, where every row is either a "0" or a "1"

When I print out the variable "myresult", it gives me a list where each item is a tuple:

```
[(bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'1'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'1'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'1'),)]
```

I need to get a string with either "0" or "1" for every item in this list

I have looked online to try and figure out how to do this, but nothing is working

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with list comprehension and `.decode()`:

```
a = [(bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'1'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'1'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'1'),)]
[i[0].decode() for i in a]
```

Output:

```
['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert from bytearray to binary value with `int` function:

```
result = [(bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'0'),), (bytearray(b'1'),)]

out = []
for i in result:
    out.append(str(int(i[0], 2)))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['0', '0', '1']
```

Comment: OP wants it as a string